# Token based authentication for API and app, can it be a simple string, or do you need more?

Tags: php, jwt, bearer-token

I am looking to rewrite an API service and looking at using token based authentication to help manage the calls through the Authorization header and Bearer tokens.

It appears that there is a divide in schools of thought between OAuth or JWT, but can this be achieved with a simple, as an example, 256-character string that is saved in a database and associated back to the users ID?

So, in my app, if I store the token to use in my API calls, I can just grab the Authorization header in my API and match-up the user with the token from my database?

Am I over simplifying this theory, or is there more that I should be considering when thinking about a token based authentication for my app/API?

Comment: FYI, OAuth is the protocol defines how a token should be transfer, JWT is the format of the token. OAuth can issue you a JWT token.

Comment: What you're proposing isn't much different than storing a password.  You would want to at least hash it so that someone snagging a copy of the database can't instantly impersonate everyone.

Comment: My 2 cents is that it's not a great idea ( imho ) to store such tokens in the db. You really want to just decode the token per request than have to make additional db calls to just authenticate. You already have the secret key in the environment, might as well just use that and do while processing the request. What are the advantages of storing it in the db ?

Comment: Thanks for the input, everyone. @ShyamPillai, my thought on storing in the database is to get access to their users ID. I didn’t want to send that information through parameters in my API calls, so I was thinking that by using the token, you can get the user ID through a relational query. Is there a better approach for getting the users ID?

Comment: The standard approach is to encode the necessary details in the token. It can even be user id. It's is encrypted using a secret key which typically we'll place in the environment of the app. No one should have access to this key. And then while processing the request you can decode the token to obtain the encoded details viz user_id etc etc.
https://jwt.io/ is a great page to understand this. The home page gives a good example of encoding & decoding.